# Métodos asíncrono como hacer para que no se pisen

Tags: c#, programacion-asincrona

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código.

```
Public void loadtacks(){
var task1 {( => 
   F1();
});
var task2 {( => 
   F2();
});
task1.Start();
task2.Start();
}

Public void F1()
{
Code
FX();
}

Public void F2()
{
Code
FX();
}

Public void FX(){code}
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que task1 espere a que se termine de usar Fx() si task2 la llamo. Y viseversa si task1 llama FX() task2 tiene que esperar a que termine FX() antes de llamarlo

Comment: Revisa sobre Task, Async y Await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar por ejemplo un lock:

```
static readonly object _object = new object();

Public void loadtacks(){
    var task1 {( => 
        F1();
    });
    var task2 {( => 
        F2();
    });
    task1.Start();
    task2.Start();
}

Public void F1()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void F2()
{
    //Code
    FX();
}

Public void FX(){
    lock (_object)  
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

De este modo, el código dentro de el bloque lock, solo podrá ser ejecutado por un hilo a la vez, si otro lo intenta, tendrá que esperar hasta que el primero acabe.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un manual reset event para intercalar y bloquear el processo ejemplo de como funcionaria:

```
 private static ManualResetEvent avsthread =
      new ManualResetEvent(false); //no es obligatorio que se declare static depende de que necessitas

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => {
          if( avsthread.WaitOne())//waitOne Bloquea el proceso hasta que recive .Set() (No es obligatorio el if) 
            FX("hola1");
          avsthread.Reset(); //reinicia el Boolean
        });
        Thread thread2 = new Thread( () => {
            if (avsthread.WaitOne())
              
            FX("hola2");
            avsthread.Reset();
        });
      
        thread1.Start();
        avsthread.Set();//inicia el intercalo 
        thread2.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public  static void FX(string text)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//Tiempo para que se abra el hilo sustituir por codigo
        Console.WriteLine(text);//prueba de que entra en los dos lados
       
        avsthread.Set();


   }
```